# Hadoop 2.1.0 beta javac compile error

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to compile the example described in http://www.cs.brandeis.edu//~cs147a/lab/hadoop-example-java/ but I get errors like :

```
MultiFetch.java:107: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Text
location: class edu.brandeis.cs147a.examples.MultiFetch.Reduce
                           OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
```

The command is:

```
`javac -classpath /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.1.0-beta.jar -d MultiFetch_classes/ MultiFetch.java` .
```

I think I'm using the wrong .jar, also tried with other .jar files but I haven't find the correct one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I used the following command to compile the example:

```
javac -classpath /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.1.0-beta.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.1.0-beta.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.1.0-beta.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar  -d MultiFetch_classes/ MultiFetch.java
```